# In Stack Overflow, how do you review an edit to a question?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I was writing an edit for a question, and it said

**Another edit is already waiting to be approved.**

So I looked around the page for a 'review edit' button or something like that, even refreshed it a few times, but I couldn't find anything. How do you review an edit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edits are reviewed in [the Suggested Edits review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).  To access it, you need to have privileges to [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), which you get at 2000 reputation points.

Also, the author of a post can instantly accept a suggested edit.

Comment: I recently made an [edit, click here to see it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24754453) to a question, and then saw that it had been approved by 'Arun kumar K', who only had 21 reputation. How is this possible?

Comment: @Run_Script: The OP can accept the suggested edit on her/his own, bypassing the review system. It happens [even if a reviewer rejected the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24547917). That is how many [dubious](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24547917) [suggestions enter the system](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24567768) (e.g. unnecessary code formatting of words, often proper nouns).